# How do I classify data into several different files depending on the attribute of the data?

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to classify a big chunk of JSON data into different files based on their attributes. Each entry in the JSON file has the key 'Region' and I would like to store all the information about a specific region in separate files. For example, if we have the regions `['US', 'Canada', 'Korea']` I want to have the files `US.csv, Canada.csv, and Korea.csv`. (I am dealing with ~15 regions in the actual data)

The order of the entries in the JSON file are not sorted by region so I don't want to open/close each time I record an entry.

Right now I am doing something like

```
`with open('US.csv', 'a') as usOut, \
      open('Canada.csv', 'a') as caOut, \
      open('Korea.csv', 'a') as krOut:
    fileNameMap = {'US': usOut, 'Canada': caOut, 'Korea': krOut}
    for entry in jsonData:
        fileNameMap[entry['Region']].write(...)
`
```

However, as I am dealing with many regions, there is a lot of code duplication for having a `with open ...` for each region. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

An option might be as such, but replacing the fields I`ve written here as appropriate for your specific situation:

```
countries = {'US':None,'Canada':None}
for country in countries:
    countryFile = country+'.txt'
    with open(countryFile, 'w') as f:
        f.write('cool')
        countries[country] = f
        f.close()
```